# Transpose and join one column SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which will be filled in the following manner:

| ID | MODELID | PROPERTYID | V | Q | T | TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | LotNumber | NULL | 1243582 | NULL | 2021-10-08 00:00:00.000 | NULL |
| 2 | GoodStrips | NULL | 39288 | NULL | 2021-10-08 00:00:00.000 | NULL |
| 3 | StripProc | NULL | 492 | NULL | 2021-10-08 00:00:00.000 | NULL |
| 4 | StripRaw | NULL | 883 | NULL | 2021-10-08 00:00:00.000 | NULL |
| 5 | LabelProc | NULL | 414 | NULL | 2021-10-08 00:00:00.000 | NULL |
| 6 | LabelRaw | NULL | 54 | NULL | 2021-10-08 00:00:00.000 | NULL |
| 7 | SmallTips | NULL | 101 | NULL | 2021-10-08 00:00:00.000 | NULL |
| 8 | LongTips | NULL | 65 | NULL | 2021-10-08 00:00:00.000 | NULL |

For each block of 8 rows, the timestamp will be identical.

Ideally, I'd like to make another table or view from this initial table where my lot number or timestamp would act as an ID column, and all the other values would be placed in the same row, like so:

| LotNumber | GoodStrips | StripProc | StripRaw | LabelProc | LabelRaw | SmallTips | LongTips | T |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1243582 | 39288 | 492 | 883 | 414 | 54 | 101 | 65 | 2021-10-08 00:00:00.000 |

I've been trying to get an inner join working to no avail.

My attempt at doing the first few as a test:

```
select m1.T, m1.MODELID, m2.V, m3.V
from Rejects945 m1
inner join Rejects945 m2 on m2.T = m1.T 
inner join Rejects945 m3 on m3.T = m1.T
where m2.V = 'GoodStrips'
where m3.V = 'StripProc'
where MODELID = 'LotNumber'
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You only use the `where` keyword once, after that you combine conditions using `AND` or/and `OR`.

Comment: What you need is a [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15) query

Comment: Thank you Dale, I think we are getting closer, I no longer have an error, but my results show as empty.

Select m1.T, m1.MODELID, m2.V, m3.V
from Rejects945 m1
inner join Rejects945 m2 on m2.T = m1.T 
inner join Rejects945 m3 on m3.T = m1.T
where m1.MODELID = 'LotNumber'
and m2.V = 'GoodStrips'
and m3.V = 'StripProc'

Comment: Thank you Squirrel, it may just be the thing. I'm giving it a go right now but I am probably misunderstanding the example giving in the documentation as it is not working unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the PIVOT function.

[PIVOT & UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15)

See sample code below:

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
ID INT
,MODELID VARCHAR(100)
,V INT
,T DATETIME
)
INSERT  #Test (ID, MODELID, V, T)
VALUES (1,'LotNumber',1243582,'8/10/2021  12:00:00 AM')
,(2,'GoodStrips',39288,'8/10/2021  12:00:00 AM')
,(3,'StripProc',492,'8/10/2021  12:00:00 AM')
,(4,'StripRaw',883,'8/10/2021  12:00:00 AM')
,(5,'LabelProc',414,'8/10/2021  12:00:00 AM')
,(6,'LabelRaw',54,'8/10/2021  12:00:00 AM')
,(7,'SmallTips',101,'8/10/2021  12:00:00 AM')
,(8,'LongTips',65,'8/10/2021  12:00:00 AM')
,(9,'LotNumber',2345234,'9/10/2021  12:00:00 AM')
,(10,'GoodStrips',4543,'9/10/2021  12:00:00 AM')
,(11,'StripProc',455,'9/10/2021  12:00:00 AM')
,(12,'StripRaw',43,'9/10/2021  12:00:00 AM')
,(13,'LabelProc',24,'9/10/2021  12:00:00 AM')
,(14,'LabelRaw',5,'9/10/2021  12:00:00 AM')
,(15,'SmallTips',2,'9/10/2021  12:00:00 AM')
,(16,'LongTips',666,'9/10/2021  12:00:00 AM')



select LotNumber
                    ,GoodStrips
                    ,StripProc
                    ,StripRaw
                    ,LabelProc
                    ,LabelRaw
                    ,SmallTips
                    ,LongTips
                    ,t
from
(
  select v, MODELID, t
  from #Test
) d
pivot
(
  max(v)
  for MODELID in (LotNumber
                    ,GoodStrips
                    ,StripProc
                    ,StripRaw
                    ,LabelProc
                    ,LabelRaw
                    ,SmallTips
                    ,LongTips
                    )
) piv;
```

Comment: Thank you guytz, it worked. I’ll study that t-code to make sure I understand it properly and I was able to create a view with it.